# Using Windows Containers directly in Azure Batch

Tags: azure, azure-batch, windows-container

I have a Docker-based Windows Container image, packaged to facilitate a very specific execution environment. It also contains the application that will run automatically when started. I have a workload to process, that varies in size (from a 100 input files all the way to 10,000 files).

Is it possible to use this image with Azure Batch:

1. Do I need the compute nodes to be VMs or can I use the containers directly?
2. Is it possible to configure elasticity, to scale (up or down) with the workload size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Updated sub-answer 2017-10-25**: As of 2017-10-19, Batch provides "native" Docker container support with the SKU `2016-Datacenter-with-Containers`. You need to specify a [ContainerConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/pool/add#definitions_containerconfiguration) on the pool and tasks' should specify [TaskContainerSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/Task/Add#definitions_taskcontainersettings). Currently, there is no direct container allocation support akin to Azure Container Instances. You can add your comments/votes to this existing [UserVoice thread](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/269742-batch/suggestions/17416279-support-for-allocating-azure-batch-nodes-using-con).
2. Yes, please see Batch [Pool Autoscaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-automatic-scaling).